# TextBox KeyBinding not found

Tags: c#, wpf, key-bindings

Used for understanding: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.inputbinding?view=netframework-4.6.1

```
public MainWindow() {
  insertNewScoreCommand = new SimpleDelegateCommand(x => this.InsertNewScore(x));

  insertNewScoreCommand.GestureKey = Key.Enter;
  insertNewScoreCommand.GestureModifier = ModifierKeys.Control;
  insertNewScoreCommand.MouseGesture = MouseAction.RightClick;
}

public SimpleDelegateCommand InsertNewScoreCommand {
   get { return insertNewScoreCommand; }
}

private SimpleDelegateCommand insertNewScoreCommand;
private void InsertNewScore(object sender)    {        }
```

I have an input field inside of a DataGrip which I want to use for inserting new scores to the database. My thought was to trigger a method when I hit Enter in the field.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Disciplines}" HeadersVisibility="None" CanUserAddRows="False"  CanUserDeleteRows="False" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DisciplineId}" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Hidden" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name }" IsReadOnly="True" Width="70"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" MinWidth="52">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBox MinWidth="50" >
            <TextBox.InputBindings>
              <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding InsertNewScoreCommand}" />
            </TextBox.InputBindings>
          </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But WPF keeps saying that the binding does not exist. It's the first time I do an KeyBinding and I don't understand what is wrong. I thought I have done all which is in the docu.

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'InsertNewScoreCommand' property not found on 'object' ''Discipline_A320C92756365475DEC4BDC8039368751EFACDCE5B74C1FE572674EA0C24C666' (HashCode=39958021)'. BindingExpression:Path=InsertNewScoreCommand; DataItem='Discipline_A320C92756365475DEC4BDC8039368751EFACDCE5B74C1FE572674EA0C24C666' (HashCode=39958021); target element is 'KeyBinding' (HashCode=18759866); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Edit: [Link to the complete source code](https://gitlab.com/svanschu/EasyCalc/tree/master/DecksummeWPF)

Comment: That textbox ends up in a row. The datacontext of a row will be one of the row viewmodels from disciplines. Not the mainwindow. Also. Your textbox will probably grab any return key press itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding will look for a specified binding Path in current binding context. By default it will be current DataContext. You can change binding context by using either ElementName, Source or RelativeSource. In your case assuming your InsertNewScoreCommand and DataGrid DataContext are in same ViewModel, you can use your DataGrid DataContext.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="disciplinesDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Disciplines}" HeadersVisibility="None" CanUserAddRows="False"  CanUserDeleteRows="False" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DisciplineId}" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="Hidden" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name }" IsReadOnly="True" Width="70"/>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" MinWidth="52">
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBox MinWidth="50" >
                   <TextBox.InputBindings>
                       <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding ElementName=disciplinesDataGrid, Path=InsertNewScoreCommand}" />
                   </TextBox.InputBindings>
               </TextBox>
           </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Hi @Aakanksha thx for nice explanation. In my case the disciplinesDataGrid is nested in another DataGrid "DecksummeAnzeige" which is the MainWindow. So I have MainWindow.xaml, MainWindows.xaml.cs and the models Participants and Disciplines. The cmd is defined in MainWindow.xaml.cs, so I would have to bin it to the MainWindow DataContext? Or would you say I have a bad design overall? [I post the Link to the repo, because alls code pasting wouldn't make sense](https://gitlab.com/svanschu/EasyCalc/tree/master/DecksummeWPF)

Comment: Why do you have the command defined in MainWindow.xaml.cs? Ideally you should create a viewmodel and add your command in the viewmodel.

Comment: well, because I didn't know it better. If I understand it right, I don't have a ViewModel class yet ... So I should look for a good example on how to add a ViewModel to my design.

Comment: Yes you should have a viewmodel and define the command in the viewmodel and set that as datacontext to your view.